# Stop User Leaving Before Postback (Javascript/ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have several functions running on a postback that can take a little time to complete.

When postback is initiated I show a loading image with this code:

```
function showLoader()
{
    document.getElementById("<%=loadingImage.ClientID%>").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

I want to be able to add code to this function so if user tries to leave at this point they are informed the operation is not complete.

I found this code:

```
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog
    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
```

This works but I only want the code to be active when the loading image is active.

I tried the following but it shows the alert message when the page eventually posts back:

```
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!e) e = window.event;
    //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'You sure you want to leave?'; //This is displayed on the dialog
    //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
function showLoader()
{
    document.getElementById("<%=loadingImage.ClientID%>").style.visibility="visible";
    window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;
}
```

Any ideas how I can tweak this to just show when user leaves page and not when postback completes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `window.onbeforeunload` to `null` when a form get submitted. So, basically:

```
<form onsubmit="window.onbeforeunload=null">
```

To apply this on all forms dynamically, I'd suggest to write a `window.onload` function for this which does this without the need to edit every single form on all your pages.